# Existence of local equations for closed subvarieties of codimension 1

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We know the following result:

Let $X$ be a quasi-projective variety and $Y \subset X$ a closed subvariety of codimension 1. If $P \in Y$ is smooth in $X$ then there exists an affine neighbourhood $U \subset X$ of $P$ and a regular function $f$ over $U$ such that the vanishing ideal of $Y \cap U$ is the ideal generated by $f$.

I tried to follow the proof but could not find why it was important that we have codimension 1. My question: What would go wrong if the codimension is greater than 1?
I also have trouble to understand what the codimension actually is. The only thing I know is that a subvariety of codimension 1 over a curve is a point.

Could you explain this to me? Thank you!

Comment: $(x,y) \subset K[x,y]$ is the non-principal vanishing ideal of $\{(0,0)\} \subset \mathbb{A}^2$.